# Pandas : How to split a column into multiple columns by separator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have one data frame :

```
df ={'date' : ['2020-08-05', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-05'], 'values_a':['jbl_1;jbl2', 'jbl44;jbl441;imax76;wer43', 'macbook12;iphone43;micromax12;ios11'], 'types' : ['connector1','connector1','connector1'], 'connection' : ['working','working','working']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

         date                             values_a       types connection
0  2020-08-05                           jbl_1;jbl2  connector1    working
1  2020-08-05            jbl44;jbl441;imax76;wer43  connector1    working
2  2020-08-05  macbook12;iphone43;micromax12;ios11  connector1    working
```

What I am looking for :

[image]

I want to split the values_a column using separator and make extra columns:

What I have tried:

```
def generate_one_hot(df):
    # make a list of all unique columns values
    all_columns =  reduce(operator.concat,[column.split(';') for column in df['values_a']])

    # fill one hot values
    all_values  = [[1 if column_name in value else 0 for value in df['values_a']]  for column_name in all_columns]

    # map it
    dataframe   = pd.DataFrame({col_name:col_val for col_name, col_val in zip(all_columns,all_values)})
    
    return pd.concat([df,dataframe],1)
```

Which is doing the job, How can I optimize this code using native pandas functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this using [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) , It's working out :

```
one_hot = pd.concat([df,df.values_a.str.get_dummies(sep=';')],1)
```